# std::vector<const A &> is not allowed

Tags: c++

What's wrong with this C++ code ?   `std::vector<const A &>` is not ok but `std::vector<const A *>` is right

```
    class A{};
    A array[10];
    std::vector<const A &> fun(){
     std::vector<const A &> ret;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            ret.push_back(arr[i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: You can't have a vector of references.

Comment: You missed ']' here: ret.push_back(arr[i);

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile

Comment: A vector of std::reference_wrapper is allowable though.